# Sorting DBAdvGrid with FIBDataSet by clicking on the column header

Tags: delphi, tms, fibplus

The only solution to the above problem i've found is to attach "ORDER BY" statement to the SQL-query of the FIBDataSet. Kind of strange because Grid has it's own quicksort() implementation but i can't get it work. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, i see some CPU activity when calling the quicksort() but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Grid's sort method commonnly do "in-memory-sort".

If you are using Devrace's FibPlus, then there is TpFibDataset which inherited from TFibDataset, which has built in implementation of SQL parsing and ORDER BY changing.